# Using Oracle's with inside procedure with sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to execute a procedure that returns a `sys_refcursor`, and I want to use a with command to get the cursor, but I get an error when I execute the proc. Is it possible? Below is the proc:

```
create or replace
procedure sp_proc(
  p_vl_skip in number,
  p_vl_take in number,
  tblresult out sys_refcursor)
as
  v_first_row number;
  v_last_row number;
begin
  select p_vl_skip into v_first_row from dual;
  select p_vl_skip + p_vl_take into v_last_row from dual;

  open tblresult for
  with tbl_relacao_rejeicoes as (
    select vl_value1, vl_value2, row_number() over (order by vl_value1 desc) vl_reg
    from tb_table
    order by vl_value1 desc)
  select *
  from tbl_relacao_rejeicoes
  where vl_reg between v_first_row and v_last_row
  order by cd_motivo_rejeicao vl_value1;
end;
/
```

It compiles without any logs, but when I execute it, I get:

```
OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TBL_RELACAO_REJEICOES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: @den You're write. My mistake. I changed to :=... After 14 hours working, one tend's to write strange code... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second order by:

> order by cd_motivo_rejeicao vl_value1;

is not valid. Is "cd_motivo_rejeicao" a column somewhere that you didn't select? If it is, put a comma between it and vl_value1. Otherwise, get rid of it. I'm also not sure why you've got the first ORDER BY in the WITH clause SELECT - it serves no purpose, does it? At any rate, I was able to get your procedure to run by fixing the second order by. So, yes you can use the WITH clause within a cursor.

Comment: Yeah... I'm so sorry... The order by I posted was wrong indeed, by it was correct in my code. The problem was that I had the procedure name wrong! Instead of executing sp_proc, I had as the procedure name. After 14 hours of coding, all the lines tend to get blurred. Tks so much!